# geocode over_query_limit and LengthAwarePaginator errors in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I try to fetch data into google map with using geocoder (because my addresses are text) but when I do that two errors pops. First one is if pass the addresses are like this: `{!!$estates[0]->address !!};` gives me `query_over_limit` and the second one is if I pass it without ZERO: `{!!$estates->address !!};` because I want to fetch all address in the DB. that gives me `LengthAwarePaginator`

```
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    var address = "{!!$estates[0]->address !!}";

    function getLocation(i) {
        return( function(results, status){
            if(status == 'OK'){
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    title: address[i][0]
                });
            } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful because: ' + status);
            }
        });
    }

    function initMap(){
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
            center: {lat: 34.652500, lng: 135.506302},
            zoom: 13
        });

        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        for(i = 0; i < address.length; i++){
            geocoder.geocode({'address': address[i][1]}, getLocation(i));
        }
    }
```

Any know how to solve this problem?

Comment: The solution for `over_query_limit` involves giving money to google. Also you should probably cache the geocoder results server-side so you don't blow through your budget geocoding the same coordinates over and over.

Comment: Wrong!! You aren't allowed to cache results as per: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/#3-license

Comment: Hi Snickers, thank you for involving me.
As stated here  https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/articles/usage-limits you just exceeded the maximum limit allowed for your free plan.

Comment: Okay, but thank you for returning me.